# Pass variable from a test method to another in CodeCeption

Tags: php, codeception

I am using Codeception to test 3 APIs:

1. Write a post comment
2. Write a reply to the comment
3. Get all comments from a post

The first API returns the ID of the comment that was just inserted into DB. I want to pass the comment Id to the second test method.

In PHPUnit I would do that by returning the commentId from the first method and annotating the second method with @depends, but in Codeception @depends does not send the returned value from the first method.

Is there any way I could send the value without placing both tests in the same method?

I am just starting to use Codeception, so I might miss some valuable information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeception runs all your tests in the same memory space, so you can just use the **GLOBAL** keyword:

```
/**
 * @test1
 */
public function testOne(){
    global $hello;
    $hello = "Hello!";
}

/**
 * @test2
 */
public function testTwo(){
   global $hello;
   $this->assertEquals("Hello!", $hello);
}
```

Comment: Using global variables should be avoided. Rather create a private method in the test and pass the var(s) to it;

Answer (score 1):

This works fine and is very straightforward. Note that functions that should not be contained in the test should be `protected`

```
 protected $var1;
 protected $var2;

public function test1(AcceptanceTester $I){
    $var1 = "Variable1";
    $var2 = "Variable2";
    $this->pass_variable($var1,$var2);
}

public function test2(AcceptanceTester $I){
    $I->doSomethingWithPassedVars($this->var1, $this->var2);
}

protected function pass_variable($var1 = "", $var2 = ""){
    $this->var1 = $var1;
    $this->var2 = $var2;
}
```